# Создание парсера постов для ВКонтакте php

Tags: php, парсер, вконтакте

Появилась необходимость написать парсер постов для Вконтакте. Используется язык PHP, а также Apache сервер.
Как выглядит:

```
$source = file_get_content('https://www.vk.com');
```

Но в результате происходит вечная загрузка страницы. Прогружается часть html - кода и тут же удаляется - повторяется бесконечно.

Answer (score 1):

Для Вашей задачи необходимо использовать API. Эта библиотека поможет Вам реализовать требуемый функционал. https://github.com/fdcore/vk.api/blob/v2/README_RU.md